# AWS Cognito and Lambda: JWT expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, amazon-cognito

I followed this example from Serverless framework in order to create a Lambda to use as an authorizer:

https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-auth0-cognito-custom-authorizers-api/auth.js

From my client i'm able to get the token but there is an issue with the timezones and it keeps returning me '*Unauthorized*' when i try to make some requests.

My **Lambdas are hosted in eu-west-1** and the Cognito iss generate a token that has an exp date with -1 hour compared to the time of the lambda region (and it's valid for 3600 seconds) so when i try to make some requests the token is already expired.
How can i solve this issue looking at the code from my example?
The jsonwebtoken documentation about this topic is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT spec recommends setting date values as [NumericDate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.html#section-2):

```
A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from 
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap 
seconds. This is equivalent to the IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] 
definition "Seconds Since the Epoch", in which each day is accounted for by 
exactly 86400 seconds, other than that non-integer values can be 
represented. See RFC 3339 [RFC3339] for details regarding date/times in 
general and UTC in particular.
```

Which means timezones should be accounted for. So simply make sure the timezone is included in your `iat` / `exp` claims or that both signer and verifier use the same timezone (for example, standard UTC).

Comment: Thanks, I have transformed the date to UTC before the verify and it worked.